# Kohana Route for blog posts not working

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, routes, custom-routes

While I was learning kohana and making single article, i encountered this problem.

I wanted to get my url to look like `article/post_id/slug(optional)` so I made the route.

`Route::set('article', '/<controller>/<article_id>(/<article_slug>(/<id1>(/<id2>(/<id3>))))', array('article_id' => '[0-9]', 'article_slug' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_]+'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'article',
        'action'     => 'read',
    ));`

I even tried without 3rd parameter for `Route::set` but anyway returns error shown in the picture.

[image: Error Mesage]

Thanks. (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without the leading /:

```
Route::set('article', '<controller>/<article_id>(/<article_slug>(/<id1>(/<id2>(/<id3>))))', 
array(
   'article_id' => '[0-9]', 
   'article_slug' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_]+')
)->defaults(
array( 
   'controller' => 'article', 
   'action' => 'read', 
));
```

Comment: after following @matino's advice you wil probably want to add a plus-sign to the article_id regex

Comment: I tried without but still got this error, even tried to remplate `<controller>` width `article/` but still nothing

Comment: Maybe you have other route that match the URL before article route is executed? Try commenting all routes except article and see if this helps.

Comment: This is the first defined route, [link](https://github.com/raimonds1503/vidfolio/blob/master/application/bootstrap.php) is the `bootstrap.php` file

Comment: It works perfectly on my computer... Have you added the + as suggested by @Darsstar? Just saw your bootstrap - I think you need to set index_file to FALSE ('index_file' => FALSE).

Comment: Changed everything as needed index_file => false and route to `Route::set('article', 'article/<article_id>(/<article_slug>(/<id1>(/<id2>(/<id3>))))', array('article_id' => '[0-9]+', 'article_slug' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_]+'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'article',
        'action'     => 'read',
    )); ` but still nothing, maybe somethings wrong with my local server config?

Comment: Are you sure you have read action in your controller? The picture you gave says you don't ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4000/discussion-between-matino-and-raimonds)